# VBA Word - Finding specific text in a document and replacing the content of the paragraph following that specific text

Tags: vba, ms-word

Here is a sample of text from my word document : 
https://www.noelshack.com/2018-31-2-1533054408-word.png

I am new to VBA and I am trying to write a macro that looks for the specific text """"Eligible Currency"" means the Base Currency and each other currency specified here:" and replace the two following lines (filled with some dots, not necessarily in the same paragraph) with a list of text (for instance : Euro, Dollar).

So far I have been able to loop through the document, find the specific text and edit it, using the code :

```
Sub FindAndFormat()
    Dim objWord As Object
    Dim wdDoc As Object
    Dim ParagraphRange As Object
    Dim intParaCount
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set wdDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("D:\Modele.docx")
    objWord.Visible = True
    Dim Paragraph As Word.Paragraph
    For Each Paragraph In wdDoc.Paragraphs
        Set ParagraphRange = Paragraph.Range
        ParagraphRange.Find.Text = """Eligible Currency"" means the Base Currency and each other currency specified here:"
        ParagraphRange.Find.Execute
        If ParagraphRange.Find.Found Then
            ParagraphRange.Text = """Eligible Currency"" means the Base Currency and each other currency specified here: Euro, Dollar"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Note that the style of the whole line is getting bold and italic.

https://www.noelshack.com/2018-31-2-1533055581-word2.png

What I really would like to achieve is replacing the dotty lines :

https://www.noelshack.com/2018-31-2-1533055647-word3.png

Now there may be several other dotty lines in my document, and they may not always contain exactly the same amount of dots.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Please take a moment to read the site guidelines in the [help] about asking on Stack Overflow. You shouldn't use any outside links - add images directly to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try something along the lines of:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = """Eligible Currency""[!:]@:[ ….^13^l^t]{2,}"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found
    .End = .End - 1
    .Start = .Start + InStr(.Text, ":")
    .Text = Chr(11) & vbTab
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Text = "Euro, Dollar"
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Font.Italic = True
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi macropod. Thanks a lot for replying so fast.
What you provided did work.
However, this is what was rended : 
https://www.noelshack.com/2018-31-3-1533114884-word4.png

The start of the paragraph after the dotty lines moved up.

Comment: Sorry for double posting. 
I would like to build more replacement effect like this one.
Would you mind explaining the different parts of the pieces of code ?

Comment: Try deleting '.End = .End - 1' and inserting ' & vbCr' after '"Euro, Dollar"'. The code uses a *wildcard* Find for "Eligible Currency", followed by any string of characters until it finds a colon followed by any combination of spaces, ellipses, periods, paragraph breaks, line breaks & tabs. It then jumps to the character after the colon, then inserts a manual line break & tab, followed by 'Euro, Dollar', which it formats bold & italic. The code uses a loop to repeat that process until all instances are done.

Comment: It is slightly better.
https://www.noelshack.com/2018-31-3-1533129761-word5.png

Notice that there is a new line between Base and Currency (not sure why).
The (b) paragraph is no longer aligned with the (a) paragraph : this is something that also occurs while I manually try to remove the dotty lines from the document.

Comment: Without seeing your actual document, it's hard to know what the issue is. I suspect you're using a poorly-formatted document with empty paragraphs used for spacing our the text. How about uploading a document to a file hosting site (e.g. One Drive) and posting a link to it?

Comment: You should be able to view the document using this link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FBt5mn6Pr4W7Xf7YUWGwp14eGF3I2H5C/view?usp=sharing

Here is an image showing all characters from it : https://www.noelshack.com/2018-31-4-1533198868-word6.png

It seems that the first replace from the macro is removing a line break and modifying the alignment of the (ii) line.

I am also wondering how we can handle "bubble" character that you can see on the (i) line. For instance if it is part of the replacement group we want to remove, how do we match it in the regular expression ?

Comment: Your document's formatting is a dog's breakfast - spaces are used instead of tabs, empty paragraphs are used instead of paragraph before/after spacing, unnecessary Section breaks are scattered here and there, Word's Normal Style is used with indiscriminate formatting throughout, etc., etc. Some logical paragraphs even have paragraph breaks in the middle of them! In the "Eligible Currency" paragraph, the second line of … isn't even terminated by a paragraph break before the (b) of the "Covered Transactions" line. You cannot reasonably expect a macro to work with such appallingly bad formatting.